# Please explain what causes AC-OFF-DET to be high (3v) and what turns on/off PC401 LED

Tags: power-supply

On connector CN2 you see AC-OFF-DET signal. This signal is supplied by the power supply schematic if an error condition is detected, however I am having trouble understanding what is setting it ON to 3v.

It is Clear that PC202 LED and transistor of the OptoIsolator must be ON to set it to LOW (lower right of schematic to right of EXT41141) but I get lost after that. PC202 LED side of the OptoIsolator (a bit left of the SSC9515 IC) seems to be turned on by Q211, which is turned on by, correct me if wrong, voltage in excess of DZ205 controlled by Q210 which is turned on by rectified voltage coming from mains? Is this right? Can someone give a clearer explanation of how that works?

Also can someone explain how PC401 Optoisolator LED (LED side to the right of the EXT41141 transformer) gets turned on?

PDF of schematic is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZluOtqBZs_RqVeU39AeBJrZs323AqZtv/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: Please copy the schematic into your post as an image instead of a link to Google Drive. Not everyone can access Google Drive and, in any case, the post must include relevant details (such as schematics) rather than linking to them.

Comment: @Null First, everyone should have access to that URL, it's public and Google Drive account/software is not required. Second, there is no way to attach a PDF to the post. Third the schematic is large and an image does not allow seeing the schematic properly unless it is very high resolution whereas with PDF one can zoom in. Lastly I tried to export it as an image and it is completely unreadable. It was a Vector image and not pixel based image so we cannot simply export it as an image as you request.